# getting an error when installing npm react-navigation

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am trying to install npm react navigation in my project using command

```
npm install --save react-navigation
```

When I tried to execute the command, I get an error saying :

```
 npm ERR! fatal: 'submodule' appears to be a git command, but we were not
 npm ERR! able to execute it. Maybe git-submodule is broken?
```

I already put the path to the Git in my environmental variables. Below is the screen shot of the error:

[image]

The path that I added in my environmental variables is below:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer\Git\cmd
```

I am not sure how to get rid of this error. I am just trying to navigate to another page when the user presses the button in my application.

```
<View>
  <TouchableHighlight style={styles.button}>
                <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Test</Text>
            </TouchableHighlight>
</View>
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This may be due to a bad installation of your `git` executable. Could you share your `git --version`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was successfully able to install react-navigation. All I have to do is execute this command:

```
npm install --save react-navigation@1.5.2
```

The sub module error disappeared. i am not sure why putting the version number fixed the error, but now it is working.

Answer (score 0):

Since the library is a JS-based solution, to install the latest version of react-navigation you only need to run:

`yarn add react-navigation`

or

`npm install --save react-navigation`

I hope this helps.

Comment: I am using the above command npm install --save react-navigation when I am getting the submodule error. I updated my question too.